# Laravel 5 Eloquent-BelongsTo hasMany give me empty object

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, has-many

I come here cause i have an issue with Eloquent relations One To Many, i've tested a lot since a week now but nothing to do. I try here for my last chance, after this, i will try Database: Query Builder, but i will prefer to perform my code with Eloquent.

To make simple, i want to show the differents furnitures use with the id task, so a task hasMany furnitures.

So i give you the problem, i made the relation into my model, when i call the function HasMany, it's returned to me an empty object...

I use php artisan tinker on git bash but after a thousand of try, it's not working.
I show you my try with GitBash and after my code.

When i do this `">>> $comments = App\BonIntervention::find(2003);"`
Tinker show me the right thing, the id "2003" to my Table related to my model, with all his components. But when i do this after:

```
"$comment = $comments->bonInterventionFournitures"
I'have this answer "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#810
     all: [],
   }"
```

And for a lot of try with different name/method his always the same, like my table are empty, but they're not....

Here you have my model for the "task", When i read the doc Laravel eloquent HastoMany, it appears that you can pass to the return, for the first parameter the namespace, for the second parameter the foreign key of the table, and for third parameter the primary key. So i did like this, i hope i didn't mistake myself.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BonIntervention extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id_TTa';
    protected $table = 'T_Taches';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function bonInterventionFournitures(){
return $this->hasMany('App\BonInterventionFournitures', 'Id_TTa', 'Id_TTaDFo');
    }
}
```

Now it's the model for furnitures. (Same method for the parameters in the return)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BonInterventionFournitures extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'T_Taches_Details_Fournitures';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id_TTaDFo';


    public function bonInterventions(){

      return $this->belongsTo('App\BonIntervention', 'Id_TTa', 'Id_TTa');
    }
}
```

I can show you my migrations for this table.
First, the table task (i not show you the entire table, because it's a lot of information.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('T_Taches', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('Id_TTa', true);
            $table->string('Responsable_TCa')->nullable()->index('Responsable_TCa');
            $table->dateTime('Date_TTa')->nullable()->default('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            $table->string('Ste_TCl')->nullable()->index('Ste_TCl');
            $table->string('Ste_Utl')->nullable()->index('Ste_Utl');
            $table->string('Adr_Liv_TCl')->nullable()->index('Adr_Liv_TCl');
            $table->string('Contact_TCo')->nullable()->index('Contact_TCo');
            $table->string('Collaborateur_TCa')->nullable()->index('Collaborateur_TCa');
            $table->string('NDevis_TDv')->nullable()->index('NDevis_TDv');
            $table->string('Devis_Type_TTa')->nullable();
            $table->string('NCommande_TDv')->nullable()->index('NCommande_TDv');
            $table->dateTime('Date_Debut_TTa')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('Date_Fin_TTa')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('Date_Demande_TTa')->nullable();
```

Now the furnitures table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('T_Taches_Details_Fournitures', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('Id_TTaDFo', true);
        $table->integer('Id_TTa')->nullable()->index('Id_TTa');
        $table->string('Class_TTaDFo')->nullable();
        $table->string('Des_TTaDFo')->nullable();
        $table->string('Ref_TTaDFo')->nullable();
        $table->float('Qte_TTaDFo', 10, 0)->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->float('PAHT_TTaDFo', 10, 0)->nullable()->default(0);
        $table->float('Tx_Mge_TTaDFo', 10, 0)->nullable()->default(1.5);
        $table->float('Vente_HT_TTaDFo', 10, 0)->nullable()->default(0);
    });
}
```

I hope you understand my question, and thanks all for watching.

**SOLVED**

I solved this and i explain why on the answer, after my post.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. In fact in my models i erase the second and third parameters.

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\BonIntervention', 'Id_TTa', 'Id_TTa');
return $this->hasMany('App\BonInterventionFournitures', 'Id_TTa', 'Id_TTaDFo');
```

I just add the second parameter in my return hasMany, just like this

```
return $this->hasMany('App\BonInterventionFournitures', 'Id_TTa');
return $this->belongsTo('App\BonIntervention');
```

Now with artisan tinker when i do this

```
$comments = App\BonIntervention::find(2003);
$comment = $comments->bonInterventionFournitures;
```

I find the right answer.